# @Autowired in @Before of spring-test is null

Tags: java, spring, mockito, autowired, spring-test

I'm facing an issue regarding spring-test, @Autowired and @Before. I have the following test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class AuditServiceImplTest {

private static final String PETICIONARIO = "peticionario";
private static final String AUDITADO = "auditado";
private static final String AUDITOR = "auditor";
private static final String URL = "url";

@Autowired
private AuditService auditService;

@Before
public void loadAutowiredResources() {
    loadAuthService();
    loadUserService();
}

private void loadAuthService() {
    AuthenticationService authenticationService = mock(AuthenticationService.class);
    when(authenticationService.getPeticionario()).thenReturn(PETICIONARIO);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(auditService, "authenticationService", authenticationService);
}

private void loadUserService() {
    UserService userService = mock(UserService.class);
    when(userService.getAtributosPerfilado(AUDITADO)).thenReturn(new Perfilado(AUDITADO));
    when(userService.getAtributosPerfilado(AUDITOR)).thenReturn(new Perfilado(AUDITOR));
    when(userService.getPermisosPeticionario(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(new Permisos(anyString()));
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(auditService, "userService", userService);
}

@Test
public void testExitoIsAuthorizedOperationAuditado() {
    assertTrue(auditService.isAuthorizedOperation(AUDITADO, URL));
}

@Test
public void testExitoIsAuthorizedOperationAuditadoAuditor() {
    assertTrue(auditService.isAuthorizedOperation(AUDITADO, AUDITOR, URL));
}
```

}

And the `AuditServiceImplTest-context.xml` file is:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.audit" />
```

When I run the tests with Maven (with eclipse IDE they run fine), in the `@Before` method the field `auditService` (whose implementation is annotated with `@Service`) is initialized for one of the `@Test`, but is `null` on the other one. Why is this?

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.package.audit</groupId>
<artifactId>audit</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.4</jackson.version>
    <!-- Variables de entorno de Maven -->
    <cfg.entorno>de</cfg.entorno>
    <cfg.cloneId>10</cfg.cloneId>
    <cfg.location>C:/Users/user/Workspace/audit/src/test/resources/</cfg.location>
    <log.location>C:/Users/user/Workspace/audit/</log.location>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.53</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>0.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>junit</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>both</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <ENTORNO>${cfg.entorno}</ENTORNO>
                    <cloneId>${cfg.cloneId}</cloneId>
                    <CFG_LOCATION>${cfg.location}</CFG_LOCATION>
                    <LOG_LOCATION>${log.location}</LOG_LOCATION>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ajc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        jcabi-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [0.12,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>ajc</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And the stack trace:

```
<testcase name="testExitoIsAuthorizedOperationAuditadoAuditor" classname="com.package.audit.service.impl.AuditServiceImplTest" time="37.355">
<error message="Target object must not be null" type="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException">java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:105)
at org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ReflectionTestUtils.java:84)
at com.grupobbva.package.service.impl.AuditServiceImplTest.loadAuthService(AuditServiceImplTest.java:43)
at com.grupobbva.package.service.impl.AuditServiceImplTest.loadAutowiredResources(AuditServiceImplTest.java:36)
```

Comment: You said "When I run the tests with Maven..." - does it run without issues when you run it from your IDE (may be related to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529667/autowiring-not-working-in-spring-3-1-2-junit-4-10-0)? Can you provide your pom.xml and a stacktrace?

Comment: @Maks Yes, it runs without issues with eclipse. I updated the question with the pom.xml and stacktrace.

Comment: Shouldn't be @ContextConfiguration("classpath:AuditServiceImplTest-context.xml")?

Comment: @Cengiz no, Spring Test Context is looking for a `<testname>-context.xml` in the same package by default, or a `@Configuration` class inside the test class.

Comment: I would say that way of setting the properties is a bit sketchy... Why are you doing it like this? If it is a unit test you should be instantiating and configuring the `AuditService` in your test class without a spring config. If it is a integration test, add the mocking to the configuration.

Comment: @carcaret Did you try to add surefire-junit47 dependency to your surefire plugin? (as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12530915/4781985)?

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not very used to writing tests yet. Directly instantiating the `AuditService` works fine, though I'd like to know why with `@Autowired` fails.

Comment: @Maks Yeah, I tried adding the dependency to surefire, but didn't seem to work.

Comment: Might be some ordering, I'm not sure. But imho your setup is flawed and you shouldn't write your test this way.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok. So if I understand correct, if it's unit testing I should instantiate the service and mock its dependencies as I did, and if it's integration testing I should do it all in the configuration files, right?

Comment: basically yes, but that is IMHO of course. Also if you are writing a real integration test you should limit the amount of mocks you have (preferably no mocks).

Comment: I agree with M. Deinum that you should likely write a pure unit test if you are mocking so many of the dependencies (unless you are testing the application of proxies for transactions, security, caching, etc.).

Comment: With regard to the issue you're facing, that seems quite odd indeed! Can you please produce a scaled down version of your project that reproduces the error and submit it (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues#readme)?

Comment: Is there any config file in the cfg.location directory?